# Is there a Dropped Call Listener

Tags: android

Does the Android SDK have the ability to to trap a Dropped Call event? If so, what is it called? I've been prowling the documentation looking for it.

Is there a difference between a hang up, and a dropped call?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the Android SDK have the ability
>   to to trap a Dropped Call event?

No.

> Is there a difference between a hang
>   up, and a dropped call?

To humans, yes. To Android, no.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit of additional information.

The Android system does know when a call is dropped for what ever reason, i.e. Congestion, No Circuit Available etc. However none of this information is parsed through to the sdk. In the source at some point android basically mashes a whole bunch of telephony related information into a few, excruciatingly vague sdk calls. For example - the only indication we get of a call end is the changed in a PhoneStateListener from OffHook to Idle. Which literally encompasses every single reason for a call ending.

Even different states of the call are mashed together. Where as we should be able to get information like whether the phone is alerting the b party or actually has an active connection, this is reduced to the three states available, offhook, idle and ringing - note ringing is only when your device is ringing, not when the person you are calling phone's ring.

Sorry to be another bearer of bad new, but alas. all we can hope for is better support at a later stage